# Replacing a key of a dictionary with a value of another dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I've two dictionaries like this

```
dict_1 = {'adbc.txt':'Text','union.pdf':'pdf', 'file1.py':'Python'}
dict_2 = {'adbc.txt':['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'], 'file1.py':['test.py', 'modified.py']}
```

I need to get the below result in Python. Could someone please help

```
result = {'a.txt':'Text','b.txt':'Text','c.txt':'Text','test.py':'Python', 'modified.py':'Python', 'union.pdf':'pdf'}
```

**'adbc.txt'** and **'file1.py'** keys are the common keys in both the dictionaries and I've to get the above result.

Comment: Can you post the code you have written to try and do this, and how it comes up short?  And maybe provide the reasoning behind your result?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary comprehension, like:

```
dict_1 = {'adbc.txt':'Text','union.pdf':'pdf', 'file1.py':'Python'}
dict_2 = {'adbc.txt':['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'], 'file1.py':['test.py', 'modified.py']}

result = {val: dict_1[key] for key, values_list in dict_2.items() for val in values_list}
print(result)
# {'a.txt': 'Text', 'b.txt': 'Text', 'c.txt': 'Text', 'test.py': 'Python', 'modified.py': 'Python'}
```

Comment: What if `dict_2` also contained another key, one *not* in `dict_1`?

Answer (score 0):

Since one of the keys in dict_1 is not in dict_2, a list comprehension would be very cumbersome.  With a simple loop:

```
result = {}
for key in dict_1.keys():
    if key in dict_2.keys():
        for file in dict_2[key]:
            result[file]=dict_1[key]
    else:
        result[key]=dict_1[key]

print(result)
# {'a.txt': 'Text', 'b.txt': 'Text', 'c.txt': 'Text', 'union.pdf': 'pdf', 'test.py': 'Python', 'modified.py': 'Python'}
```